# How to Filter Products Based on Attribute Value "Yes"

Tags: magento-1.9, module, product-attribute, custom, filter

I have an attribute for a custom module which defines if a user can comment on the products or not.
Now I need to filter products depending on the attribute value and only display those with attribute value "Yes".
(It's a select attribute with values "Yes", "No")

Tried this code, but it only displays those products, which are NOT allowed for commenting and have the attribute value "No":

```
      <?php
      $optionId = "Yes"; // this should be option id
      $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addAttributeToFilter('product_comment', array('eq' =>$optionId));
      foreach($products as $_data1){
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($_data1->getName());       
      } 
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What this error says is that it tries to load an attribute but couldn't find one. Does `product_comment` attribute exist and it is of `catalog_product`  type ?

Also replace this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array('apparel_type'=>'Yes'));
```

with this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('apparel_type','Yes');
```

And try.

Comment: Hi Konstantin. Thanks for your response.I added the attribute generating code to my question.  
And changed that line above like you suggested.

Comment: But still getting the error.

Comment: use addAttributeToFilter() for eav attribute and addFieldToFilter() for custom table @bestwebdevs

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not setting backend_model** for given attribute then just **remove that** from attribute creation parameter array.

and try to **filter by eav attribute using**

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('apparel_type','Yes');
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond Gopal, but I didn't quite get how to do that. I changed addFieldToFilter to addAttributeToFilter, but it didn't work. What else should I change?

Answer (score 1):

The above code not works because your attribute type is select (drop-down), and you are try filtering product based on yes/no attribute the following code should work :

```
$optionId = 1; // this should be option id
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('product_comment', array('eq' =>$optionId));


foreach($products as $_data1){

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_data1->getName()); die('ok');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your respond.  With this code I only get the name of the product, which is NOT allowed for commenting. I will update my code now.

Comment: with this code I only get the names of the products, which are NOT allowed for commenting.(updated my code now)
I need to display those products that are Allowed for commenting, with attribute value "Yes". Also, could you help to display the product with the image and it's name with link to product detail page, instead of just the name. Thank you.

Comment: @bestwebdevs you can get the product url and image like: $_data1->getUrlKey(); and $_data1->getThumbnail();

Comment: Hi @Arunendra, that didn't work unfortunately. It says "no selection" and "p/r/prod1.jpg". And also my filtering by the attribute value doesn't work at all, it displays 2 product with attribute value "No" instead of "Yes".